# Keep few columns and keep rest based on data entered

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Hi I have an excel sheet with 5 similar columns for each month(jan, Feb and so on).

[image]

I have VBA code that will automatically make columns for the next following month (in this case that would be march). After entering the march data I want my file to get saved as March.xls deleting the data for the rest of the month (while retaining all months data in the original file). is there a way to do that with VBA? I would appreciate your responses reagrding the same. I want my each month file to get "saved as" below: [image]

I found the code below online and it is doing the work. The only problem is that I have to enter the name of the column I want to delete in this code, for eg: "April" in the code. Is it possible to make this code work in a manner that will automatically keep the last four columns and first (ID column), and delete the rest. Thanks

```
Sub DeleteData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ColList As String, ColArray() As String
    Dim LastCol As Long, i As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long, j As Long
    Dim boolFound As Boolean
    Dim delCols As Range, delCols1 As Range, delCols2 As Range, delCols3 As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ColList = "April"
    ColArray = Split(ColList, ",")
    LastCol = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Column
    For i = 8 To LastCol
    boolFound = False
    For j = LBound(ColArray) To UBound(ColArray)
    If UCase(Trim(ws.Cells(1, i).Value)) = UCase(Trim(ColArray(j))) Then
    boolFound = True
    Exit For
    End If
    Next
    If boolFound = False Then
    If delCols Is Nothing Then
    Set delCols = ws.Columns(i)
    Else
    Set delCols = Union(delCols, ws.Columns(i))
    End If
    End If
    Next i
    If Not delCols Is Nothing Then delCols.Delete
```

Comment: Is this different from this question you recently asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079915/make-separate-file-based-on-each-months-data

Comment: Not really but I think I deleted my previous question. It didnt have the code as I have in this question.

Comment: @ Marc: Also, there was not any responses in the previous one. So, I just researched more about the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Copyandsave()
    Dim i As Long
    Rows("1:2").Select 'based on which rows that the name of months are inside let's suppose it is in row 1 or 2
        For Each cell In Selection 'search through aforementioned rows  for march label you can change it for other months


    If InStr(cell.Text, January) Or InStr(cell.Text, February) Or InStr(cell.Text, March) _
    Or InStr(cell.Text, April) Or InStr(cell.Text, May) Or InStr(cell.Text, June) _
    Or InStr(cell.Text, July) Or InStr(cell.Text, August) Or InStr(cell.Text, September) _
    Or InStr(cell.Text, October) Or InStr(cell.Text, November) Or InStr(cell.Text, September) Then
              i = 1 + i
          cell.Select
          Columns(Selection.Column).Select 'gets column number of cell
          Selection.Cut

        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Workbooks(1).path & i & ".xls", _
                FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
                ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False 'saves the document with name

    End If
                 Workbooks(1).Activate

        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: @ David, Thank you for your response. The code only keeps the last column for selected month. In the figure above, for eg: it would only keep Col4 for March and delete the rest.

Comment: I've just edited the code, remember the main file must be  the first excel file that you have opened. and don't forget to get a backup file because when vba deletes a columns you can not undo changes. hope this work